# cast type from jagged array (int[*,*]) to 2d array (int[][])

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, casting

How can I cast int[*,*] to int[][]

When I try, below given error occurred.
cannot implicitly convert type  "`int[*,*]` to `int[][]`"

My aim is first creating a Jagged array and then converting it to a 2d array.

```
 private int[][] initStaticBoard()
    {

        int[,] board = new int[,] {
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0}
        };
        int[][] result = board; 

        return result*emphasized text*;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no cast between a square array and a jagged array. You will have to reconstruct `board` into a jagged array:

```
public static T[][] SquareArrayToJAggedArray<T>(T[,] square)
{
    T[][] jagged = new T[square.GetLength(0)][];

    for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++)
    {
        jagged[i] = new T[square.GetLength(1)];

        for (int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++)
        {
            jagged[i][j] = square[i, j];
        }
    }

    return jagged;
}
```

And call it like so:

```
private int[][] initStaticBoard()
{
    int[,] board = new int[,] {
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0}
    };

    int[][] result = SquareArrayToJaggedArray(board); 
    return result;
}
```

Rather than worrying about the conversion, though, I would just recommend that you pick one or the other and stick to it. Converting between the two involves allocating new memory for the new array, which can add up pretty fast if you are dealing with large arrays or are converting too frequently. In addition, because of the reconstruction, changes to the new array don't affect the old array and vice versa.

If the data you are representing is a structure with a fixed width and length, then use a square array. If different subarrays will have different lengths, use a jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

Jagged arrays can be initialized like this:

```
int[][] board = { new int[5], new int[5], new int[5], new int[5], new int[5] };
```